# Unexpected non-equality after assignment

Tags: c#

Given the following code:

```cs
using System;

class MyClass
{
    public MyClass x;
}

public static class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var a = new MyClass();
        var b = new MyClass();
        a.x = (a = b);
        Console.WriteLine(a.x == a);
    }
}
```

The first two lines are very obvious, just two different objects.

I assume the third line to do the following:

- The part `(a = b)` assigns `b` to `a` and returns `b`, so now `a` equals `b`.
- Then, `a.x` is assigned to `b`.

That means, `a.x` equals to `b`, and also `b` equals to `a`. Which implies that `a.x` equals to `a`.

However, the code prints `False`.

What's going on?

Comment: Have a look at [sharplab](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgxg9gTgpgtADwGwBYA+ABATARgLABQ2ADIdgMwAEA3oZfZdljXQ2wG4CGUlnlAvJQB2MAO6UAsgE8AwgBtOAZ0UAKAJQBuVmx2UuPYAOFjJshcvVaCu3ZwB0CI30HArNnRhwBOFfcf8XTW1KAF9CMIJCYOxTeSVFYNprGwwqaTjlSgQ3BhCgA) for details under the hood

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski Why the code was converted that way? Is it a compiler bug?

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski you have a type on `a.x == b` instead of `a.x == a`

Comment: I don't think, that it's a bug. It seems, that `a.x` is being overwritten when `a` assigned to `b` and has `null` value (because `b.x` is `null`)

Comment: Why does `b.x` even matter? I didn't access it anywhere. I'm still not getting where my analysis went wrong.

Comment: when you compare two instances of classes a & b they are never equal because you are comparing the memory address and not the value.  In this case a.x is null and a is the address of the instance.

Comment: @jdweng OP knows that, they were expecting `a.x` to reference `b`, but it's isn't, that's what they are asking.

Comment: They were expecting a TRUE and got FALSE.

Comment: No-one should ever write code like `a.x = (a = b)` (except to use as an example of code no-one should ever write).

Comment: Possibly interesting sidenote: C# evaluates the LHS of an assignment before the RHS; but C++ (since C++17) evaluates the RHS before the LHS! My blog post might be interesting even to a C# programmer if you skip all the crazy variadic-template stuff: https://quuxplusone.github.io/blog/2020/05/07/assignment-operator-fold-expression/#but-wait-if-x-y-z-is-basically-e  Both C# and C++ distinguish "order of evaluation" from "order of operations" (precedence).

Comment: @Quuxplusone Because it *does* look useful and relevant, I took the liberty of editing your comment to change that pronoun "This" to "My", in accordance with [our disclosure requirements](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion) to avoid the appearance of improper self-promotion. Please adjust any future comments or answers that refer to your blog accordingly. Thanks!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It happens because you're trying to update `a` twice in the same statement. `a` in `a.x=` refers to the old instance. So, you're updating `a` to reference `b` and the old `a` object field `x` to reference `b`.

You can confirm with this:

```
void Main()
{
    var a = new MyClass(){s="a"};
    var b = new MyClass() {s="b"};
    var c =a;

    a.x = (a=b);
    Console.WriteLine($"a is {a.s}");
    Console.WriteLine(a.x == b);

    Console.WriteLine($"c is {c.s}");       
    Console.WriteLine(c.x == b);
}

class MyClass
{
    public MyClass x;
    public string s;
}
```

The answer will be:

```
a is b
False
c is a
True
```

Edit: Just to make a little bit more clear, It's not about the operators' execution order, it's because of the two updates in the same variable in the same statement. The assigment `(a=b)` is executed before the `a.x=`, but it doesn't matter, because `a.x` is referencing the old instance, not the newly updated one. This happens, as @Joe Sewell answer explains, because evaluation, to find the assignment target, is left to right.

Comment: But it *is* about execution order. First the left hand side is evaluated/executed, which uses the old `a`, then the right hand side is, which updates `a` but does not change the target of the pending `=`, which has already been fixed. You can more clearly see the left to right execution in something like `c[a += b] += a`.

Comment: @HTNW, yeah, I was talking about execution order of both `=`, should've made that clearer. After all, to know that `a.x` points to the old object, it must had been evaluated first.

Answer (score 16):

In `a.x = (a = b)`, the left hand side `a.x` is evaluated first to find the assignment target, then the right hand side is evaluated.

This was also surprising to me, because I intuitively think it starts on the rightmost side and evaluates leftward, but this is not the case. (The [*associativity*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/#operator-associativity) is right-to-left, meaning the parentheses in this case are not needed.)

[Here's the specification calling out the order things happen in](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/expressions#simple-assignment), with the relevant bits quoted below:

> The run-time processing of a simple assignment of the form `x = y` consists of the following steps:
>
> - If `x` is classified as a variable:
>
>   - `x` is evaluated to produce the variable.
>   - `y` is evaluated and, if required, converted to the type of `x` through an implicit conversion.
>   - [...]
>   - The value resulting from the evaluation and conversion of `y` is stored into the location given by the evaluation of `x`.

Looking at the IL generated by [the sharplab link](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgxg9gTgpgtADwGwBYA+ABATARgLABQ2ADIdgMwAEA3oZfZdljXQ2wG4CGUlnlAvJQB2MAO6UAsgE8AwgBtOAZ0UAKAJQBuVmx2UuPYAOFjJshcvVaCu3ZwB0CI30HArNnRhwBOFfcf8XTW1KAF9CMIJCYOxTeSVFYNprGwwqaTjlSgQ3BhCgA) Pavel posted:

```
        // stack is empty []
newobj instance void MyClass::.ctor()
        // new instance of MyClass on the heap, call it $0
        // stack -> [ref($0)]
stloc.0
        // stack -> []
        // local[0] ("a") = ref($0)
newobj instance void MyClass::.ctor()
        // new instance of MyClass on the heap, call it $1
        // stack -> [ref($1)]
stloc.1
        // stack -> []
        // local[1] ("b") = ref($1)
ldloc.0
        // stack -> [ref($0)]
ldloc.1
        // stack -> [ref($1), ref($0)]
dup
        // stack -> [ref($1), ref($1), ref($0)]
stloc.0
        // stack -> [ref($1), ref($0)]
        // local[0] ("a") = ref($1)
stfld class MyClass MyClass::x
        // stack -> []
        // $0.x = ref($1)
```

Answer (score 5):

Just to add some `IL` fun into the discussion:

The `Main` method header looks next way:

```
method private hidebysig static void
    Main() cil managed
  {
    .maxstack 3
    .locals init (
      [0] class MyClass a,
      [1] class MyClass b
    )
```

The `a.x = (a=b);` statement is translated to the next `IL`:

```
IL_000d: ldloc.0      // a
IL_000e: ldloc.1      // b
IL_000f: dup
IL_0010: stloc.0      // a
IL_0011: stfld        class MyClass::x
```

First two instructions load ([ldloc.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.ldloc_0?view=netcore-3.1), [ldloc.1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.ldloc_1?view=netcore-3.1)) onto evaluation stack references stored in `a` and `b` variables, lets call them `aRef` and `bRef`, so we have next evaluation stack state:

```
bRef
aRef
```

The [`dup`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.dup?view=netcore-3.1) instruction copies the current topmost value on the evaluation stack, and then pushes the copy onto the evaluation stack:

```
bRef
bRef
aRef
```

The [stloc.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.stloc_0?view=netcore-3.1) pops the current value from the top of the evaluation stack and stores it in a the local variable list at index 0 (`a` variable is set to `bRef`), leaving stack in next state:

```
bRef
aRef
```

And finally [`stfld`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.stfld?view=netcore-3.1) poppes from the stack the value (`bRef`) and the object reference/pointer (`aRef`). The value of field in the object (`aRef.x`) is replaced with the supplied value (`bRef`).

Which all result in the behavior described in the post, with both variables (`a` and `b`) pointing to the `bRef` with `bRef.x` being null and `aRef.x` pointing to `bRef`, which can be checked with extra variable containing `aRef` as [@Magnetron](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5762332/magnetron) suggested.

Answer (score 2):

Interesting find, I've put your code into Sharplab and checked what happens.

Seems like compiler swaps left operands in your assignment, this is what it looks like decompiled back to C# (variable names are changed):

```cs
public static void Main()
{
    MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
    MyClass x = new MyClass();
    myClass = (myClass.x = x);
    Console.WriteLine(myClass.x == myClass);
}
```

So what happens is `a.x` becomes `b` and then `b` is assigned to `a`. Both local variable `a` and attribute `a.x` now point to `b` object.
So:

- `a` variable points to `b` object
- `b` variable points to `b` object
- `a` object's `x` attribute points to `b` object
- `b` object's `x` attribute is null

I changed your code a bit to illustrate that better:

```cs
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var a = new MyClass();
    var originalA = a;
    a.Name = "a";
    var b = new MyClass();
    b.Name = "b";
    a.x = (a = b);

    Console.WriteLine(a.x == a);

    Console.WriteLine("a           - " + a.Name);
    Console.WriteLine("a.x         - " + a.x?.Name);

    Console.WriteLine("b           - " + b.Name);
    Console.WriteLine("b.x         - " + b.x?.Name);

    Console.WriteLine("originalA   - " + originalA.Name);
    Console.WriteLine("originalA.x - " + originalA.x?.Name);
}
```

That code returns:

```
False
a           - b
a.x         - 
b           - b
b.x         - 
originalA   - a
originalA.x - b
```

Notice only `originalA` now points to actual `a` object, other local variables now point to `b`.

It's not a compiler bug - see Magnetron's answer.

Comment: Why in the first place the compiler swaps things I don't want to?

Comment: I've also written the same code in Java and it prints false, which is really weird too.

Comment: I think it has something to do with how operator precedence works, but I don't have that knowledge...
Also - don't do that :P. It doesn't seem like usual way of writing things, try to avoid complicated code like that

Comment: Yes I always avoid such code. But the code just came on my hand and I couldn't figure out what's going on. So, I asked here.

Comment: And no, doesn't seem like operator precedence problem because I included parentheses.

Comment: The same happens in the debug mode without any optimizatios.

Comment: @Youssef13 and Daniel It's not execution order, it's because two updates in the same variable in the same statement. `(a=b)` is executed first, but it doesn't matter because `a.x` is referecing the old instance, not the newly updated one

Comment: I edited my answer, tried to remove misleading statements.